# clean database then synch

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a back up of a two databases, one provisioned database for the server and one provisioned database for the client. I reuse the back up of the client many times since there will be a lot of nodes. After restoring the databases, I run a script to delete records from some tables then I run a Post Restore Fix Up on the databases.

What I'm trying to do is sort of clean the databases to start from scratch. But when syncing, some scopes don't sync. Am I doing something wrong when cleaning the database? Should I clean the meta data too?

Comment: some scopes don't sync... error message?

Comment: no, they don't show up on the server database after syncing. the records from the needs are supposed to be pulled.

Comment: Have you checked that the provisioning scope includes what you require?

Comment: If you're cleaning the databases from start anyway, then why not just deprovision, truncate and reprovision? What are you trying to accomplish with doing a post restore fix up?

Comment: I changed some stored procedures generated after provisioning based on our business rules so it will be additional work if I would change it again every time I provision. What I'm trying with post restore fix up is to somehow reset the sync data between the server and the nodes so sync framework will treat the new restored database as a fresh node.

Comment: then why not create a new scope and specify during the provisioning that you want to reuse existing stored procedures, triggers, etc? have you also check for conflicts being fired when you do a sync?

Comment: What I did now is have copies of pre-provisioned clean databases, and then when a client is to be added, I just provision the restored clean database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had is that after restoring the databases, I run the `PerformPostRestoreFixUp` on the restored DB and then run a script that clears the tracking table and update the `scope_info.scope_sync_knowledge` to null which causes the syncing to have issues.